# If x in y does not equal 0 then replace with 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I am trying to see what segment of the dataframe has the most complete data.

As in there are three potential surveys that users could have filled out and I am trying to establish which industry has the highest level of users who filled out all three surveys.

Consequently I am not concerned with the numeric response, rather whether the data is present, so I am trying to change all data that is not a 0 to a 1 so I can count the total volume on full responses by industry.

How would I go about doing this for a dataset that has only 2 columns of string data (classification data) with the rest being float.

I have tried a `.replace` however it did not work.

```
brands = brands.replace([>0.001], 1)
```

I want to change the data from

```
a  c    23.45  232.40  2123.000
b  d    0      0       0
e  g    2.21   0.61    0
```

To

```
a  c    1      1       1
b  d    0      0       0
e  g    1      1       0
```

Comment: Show us 1) a sample of the data, 2) the code you have tried.

Comment: *it did not work* is not enough of a problem description. Can you instead give us a sample dataframe and code that demonstrates your problem? Include expected output as well as actual output (full tracebacks if there are errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
brands[brands > 0.001] = 1
```

Also see [the docs about indexing and selecting data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-where-method-and-masking).